# What are the main properties of eigenvalues of normal unbounded operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

I am interested in the properties of the eigenvalues of unbounded normal operators. For compact linear operators we have that for every $t >0$, the set of distinct eigenvalues $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda| > t$ is finite. Is there something like this for unbounded normal linear operators? Are there any other easy to understand properties of the eigenvalues of unbounded normal linear operators? For example, are they countable? I hope this question is well-posed. If it is not, please let me know, and I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normal operators on a Hilbert space, eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are always
orthogonal.  Thus if the Hilbert space is separable, there are at most countably many eigenvalues.  In a non-separable Hilbert space, this is no longer true.  For example,
consider $\ell^2(\Gamma)$, the Hilbert space of square-summable functions on an uncountable set $\Gamma$, and the  multiplication operator $M_g$ corresponding to an unbounded function 
 $g:\Gamma \to \mathbb C$.  Then all members of the range of $g$ are eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of whether the set of eigenvalues are bounded in any sense?

Comment: There's no reason for the set of eigenvalues to be bounded unless the operator is bounded.  The spectrum of an unbounded normal operator is certainly unbounded.